# Select and substitute whole word before a special character

Tags: vim, substitution

I have this content in my file:

```
{
  "performanceHighToLow" : {
    tabs     : {
      bySales : "by sales",
      byOrder : "by order"
    },
    category : "performanceHighToLow",
    onTabClick
  },
  performanceLowToHigh : {
    tabs     : {
      bySales : "by sales",
      byOrder : "by order"
    },
    category : "performanceLowToHigh",
    onTabClick
  }
}
```

I was wondering if I could write a regex to quote all dequoted words. On the same subject, is there a way to select full word(word boundary) before the colon(:) occurrence.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl I couldn't figure out how to do this, I had limited knowledge like a whole word can be selected by \b. I wasn't sure how to go left after the colon and how to omit spaces in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match words before a colon you could match word character + possible whitespace + colon, but stopping the match after the word itself with `\ze`:

```
/\w\+\ze\s*:
```

To also match the possible last word in a line (line `onTabClick`) you could modify the previous pattern with an or at the colon / EOL:

```
/\w\+\ze\s*\(:\|$\)
```

In which case it could be easier to enable very-magic to simplify escaping:

```
/\v\w+\ze\s*(:|$)
```

To then "quote" these results:

```
:%s/\v\w+\ze\s*(:|$)/"&"/g
```